# Difference of fct_reorder and reorder

Tags: r, forcats

This is an exmaple of fct_reorder

`boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ fct_reorder(Species, Sepal.Width, .desc = TRUE), data = iris)`
[image]

This code is identical with `boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ reorder(Species, -Sepal.Width), data = iris)`

What is the better point  `fct_reorder()` than `reorder()`?

Comment: The default summary functions here are `median` for `fct_reorder` and `mean` for `reorder`. Other than that, there does not appear to be much differences.

Answer (score 0):

The two functions are very similar, but have a few differences:

- `reorder()` works with atomic vectors and defaults to using `mean()`.
- `fct_reorder()` only works with factors (or character vectors) and defaults to using `median()`

Example:

```r
library(forcats)

x <-  1:10
xf <- factor(1:10)
y <-  10:1

reorder(x, y)
#>  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#> attr(,"scores")
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#> 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
#> Levels: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

reorder(xf, y)
#>  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#> attr(,"scores")
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#> 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
#> Levels: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

fct_reorder(x, y) 
#> Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).

fct_reorder(xf, y)
#>  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#> Levels: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>