# arrange vs. fct_reorder: Do they do the same thing?

Tags: r, dplyr

Related: [Difference of fct_reorder and reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51378506/109941)

---

Consider the code below from [here](https://youtu.be/nx5yhXAQLxw) and [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/data-screencasts/blob/master/college-majors.Rmd).

My question:

- What is the benefit of `arrange(desc(Median))` if there is an `fct_reorder(Major, Median)` beneath it?

---

```
library(tidyverse)

recent_grads <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2018/2018-10-16/recent-grads.csv")
majors_processed <- recent_grads %>%
  arrange(desc(Median)) %>% # What is the benefit of doing this if we have an fct_reorder below and vice-versa? Don't they do the same thing?
  mutate(Major = str_to_title(Major),
         Major = fct_reorder(Major, Median))

majors_processed %>%
  View()
```

Comment: `arrange` reorders rows. `fct_reorder` reorders factor levels. They are principally different things. Note that after the `arrange` one could just as well use `fct_inorder` instead of `fct_reorder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Axeman noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013058/arrange-vs-fct-reorder-do-they-do-the-same-thing#comment94864896_54013058):

> `arrange` reorders rows. `fct_reorder` reorders factor levels. They
>   are principally different things. Note that after the `arrange` one
>   could just as well use `fct_inorder` instead of `fct_reorder`.